# Diffusion equation versus evolution equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

My question may seem silly , but I would like to enquire about the diffusion equation and the evolution equation whether they are the same equation or not ?

Answer (score 2):

"[Evolution equation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Evolution_equation)" is a very general term.  An evolution equation is a (partial or ordinary) differential equation that describes how some system changes with time.  If it's a partial differential equation, it might be a [diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation), or it might not.